# When I call "new Object()" without storing the return, what happens to the returned object?

Tags: java

Let's say we have some code that looks like the following (which I am aware is bad practice):

```
try {

new myObject();

} catch {

//stuff

}
```

What happens to the returned object? Is it still stored on the heap? Should this throw a compile time error?

Comment: It is created, and then immediately eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: The Object is created, and it will be eligible for garbage collection after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is created, and is then immediately eligible for garbage collection.

I don't see any reason why it should throw an exception (unless, of course, one is thrown by the `MyObject` constructor), it is perfectly legal syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite right; objects aren't *marked* as eligible for GC as references are added and removed. *When the GC runs*, it will note which objects aren't reachable.

Comment: Well, whether it gets an actual mark or not is not really interesting IMO, you could say `it is eligible` instead of `it gets marked as ready`. The point is the same.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "not quite" :)

Comment: I agree that your phrasing is slightly better though, so changed it.

Comment: It could throw an `OutOfMemoryError`, not that there's a whole lot you could probably do at that point.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, this code will produce a compile time error

```
try {
    new myObject();
} catch {             <-- syntax error
//stuff
}
```

2) If you were trying to catch a compile time error it would not work even with a correct syntax

3) If we fix try / catch problem, then MyObject will be sucessfully created (unless its constructor throws an exception) but since there is no reference to it from anywere in the code it will probably become eligible for GC as any other object. "Probably" because it is not necessarily so, consider this

```
class MyObject {
    static MyObject myObect;  <-- this field will be preventing the instance from GC
     MyObject() {
         myObject = this;
     }
}
```

After creation MyObject stored a reference to itself in a static field which will keep it alive, but if you call new MyObject() it will overwrite the previous reference, etc

Answer (score 2):

It will be eligible for garbage-collection. Not necessary to be garbage-collected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't throw an exception because it can be perfectly valid code.  Your constructor of that object could have side effects.  It could write a file.  It could increment a static variable.  It could mutate an object you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The object doesn't get marked as ready for GC instantly. It will only get marked as such when there are no active threads left that can access the object (in this context). I don't really see the point in doing this though, the GC of java can't be invoked by the developer directly; It will only run when java thinks it's needed.

Why would someone create an object which cannot be directly referenced and used after it's created, anyway? It would be like you're creating a magical black box that does things behind the scenes that you cannot track, leaving you to the mercy of the GC.

The object itself won't generate an exception though, it's as already remarked multiple times, a perfectly valid syntax. The object does get stored on the heap though, but on the next run of the GC it will get deleted (if the object is done doing things by that time).

This is my take on this anyway :X I'm not an authority by any extent, probably a newbie even. Got most of the info about GC from this link:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html